# By using ngRoute, ng-view not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route, angular-factory

I want to implement `ngRoute` in my angularjs project. But`<ng-view></ng-view>` doesn't show anything. I read all other posts about this problem, but my problem is not resolved.

I define `$routeProvider` in app.js file as follows:

```
'use strict'
 angular.module('confusionApp',  ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)  {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/contactus', {   //  route   for the contactus page
           templateUrl :    'contactus.html',   controller      :   'ContactController'
    })

    .when('/menu',  {   //  route   for the menu    pag
           templateUrl :    'menu.html',    controller      :   'MenuController'
    })

    .when('/menu/:id',  {   //  route   for the dish    details pag
           templateUrl :    'dishdetail.html',  controller      :   'DishDetailController'
    })

    .otherwise('/contactus');
}]);
```

My controllers.js file includes the defenition of all my controllers:

```
angular.module('confusionApp',[])

    .controller('MenuController',['$scope','menuFactory',function($scope,menuFactory){

        $scope.dishes = menuFactory.getDishes();
         //other codes which deleted for simplicity

    }])

    .controller('dishDetailController',['$scope','$routeParams',
            'menuFactory', function($scope,$routeParams,menuFactory){

        var dish = menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));
        this.dish = dish;
         //other codes which deleted for simplicity

    }])

    .controller('contactController',['$scope',function($scope){

           //some code here

    }])

    .controller('feedbackController',['$scope',function($scope){

           //some code here

    }]);
```

And I defined factory in services.js file as follows:

```
angular.module('confusionApp')

   .factory('menuFactory',function(){

        var menufac = {};

        var dishes=[{... some data ...}];

        menufac.getDishes = function(){
            return dishes;
        };

        menufac.getDish = function(index){
            return dishes[index];
        };

        return menufac;
    });
```

In my index.html page `<ng-view></ng-view>` doesn't show anything. Also I define scripts in index.html as follows and all the paths are true.

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you redefining your module: `angular.module('confusionApp',[])` instead of `angular.module('confusionApp')` in your controller.js?

Comment: angular.module('confusionApp',[]) will redefine new module in your controller, So you need to use angular.module('confusionApp').... this statement fetches your angular module.

Comment: Thanks @DTing. Your guidance was right. :-)

Comment: Thanks @Hemakumar. Your guidance was right. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the dependency injection part from controller.js file

Change

**From**

```
angular.module('confusionApp',[])
```

**To**

```
angular.module('confusionApp')
```

Comment: @sahar can you create a plunker?

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem was solved. :-)